# why return "Promise { <pending> }" all the times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, promise

```
exports.getNews = async (category) =>{ //get a promise from api for display it in mustach template

  exports.fetch_news_from_API =  async (category) => { // get data from api
    /* get data from api*/
    return data.articles; // promise
  }

  exports.getData = async (data) =>{ // add an id for every news
    let finalData = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      let news = {
        id : i,
        title : data[i].title,  //api object
        author : data[i].author,
        description : data[i].description,
        publishedAt : data[i].publishedAt,
      }
      finalData.push(news);
    }
    return finalData; // news
  }
  
  let data = await this.fetch_news_from_API(category);
  let news = await this.getData(data);
  return news; // return pending all the time whene i use it in app.get
}
```

**I would like to use "news" to display it but I can not because it returns all the time "pending"
thank you in advance**

Comment: At the top level, a caller must say `fetch_news_from_API(category).then(news => /* use the news here */)`.  In another async function,  a caller can say `let news = await fetch_news_from_API(category)`

Comment: Do not assign to `exports` from inside a function!

Comment: @danh Why? Top-level `await` is supported by all maintained Node.js versions (available since Node.js v14.8).

Comment: Why is `getData` async? Unrelated, but it’s usually best to pick a single naming convention instead of switching_back andForth.

Comment: the problem is when i use it in `app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {"data": model.getNews(category)});
})` it return  { <pending> }, i saw that i can do this:`model.getNews(category).then((result){ console.log(result)})`  but what about the return statement ?